# How to show image after downloaded in Android

Tags: java, android

I want develop android application for one site, in `MainActivity` i show post image and post title and i want show this datas in another `Activity`.
I can show this datas in another activity, i send this data with `putExtra` in `MainActivity` to another `Activity`! but when use this way, first show datas (text and base image) and after a few seconds load image! but i want first load image (from url) then show this datas!
**MainActivity codes:**

```
public class Main_page extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final long RIPPLE_DURATION = 250;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private RelativeLayout root;
    private ImageView menu_image, toolbar_refresh;
    private RecyclerView main_recyclerView;
    private MainAdapter_loadMore mAdaper;
    private List<MainDataModel> dataModels = new ArrayList<MainDataModel>();
    protected Handler handler;
    private RelativeLayout loadLayout;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private int pageCount = 1;
    String ServerAddress = ServerIP.getIP();
    private Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_page);
        if (!EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this)) {
            EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
        }
        // Initializing
        handler = new Handler();
        context = getApplicationContext();
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_toolbar);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        loadLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_empty_layout);
        toolbar_refresh = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_update);
        // Toolbar
        if (toolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
        }
        // Load First Data
        LoadData();
        // Menu
        root = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_root);
        View guillotineMenu = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.menu_layout, null);
        root.addView(guillotineMenu);
        menu_image = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_logo);
        new GuillotineAnimation.GuillotineBuilder(guillotineMenu, guillotineMenu.findViewById(R.id.menu_layout_image), menu_image)
                .setStartDelay(RIPPLE_DURATION)
                .setActionBarViewForAnimation(toolbar)
                .setClosedOnStart(true)
                .build();
        // RecyclerView and setData
        main_recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.main_recycler);
        main_recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        main_recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mAdaper = new MainAdapter_loadMore(this, main_recyclerView, dataModels);
        main_recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdaper);
        // Load More data
        mAdaper.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
                dataModels.add(null);
                mAdaper.notifyItemInserted(dataModels.size() - 1);
                LoadMoreData(pageCount);
            }
        });

        // Refresh Data
        toolbar_refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PostShow_page.class));
            }
        });
    }

    @Subscribe
    public void onEvent(List<MainDataModel> mainInfoModels) {
        if (dataModels.size() > 0) {
            dataModels.remove(dataModels.size() - 1);
            mAdaper.notifyItemRemoved(dataModels.size());
            mAdaper.setLoaded();
        }

        mAdaper.add(mainInfoModels);
        mAdaper.notifyDataSetChanged();
        pageCount++;

        if (dataModels.isEmpty()) {
            main_recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            loadLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else {
            main_recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            loadLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    private void LoadData() {
        MainDataInfo dataInfo = new MainDataInfo();
        // here getMainDataInfo() should return the server response
        dataInfo.getMainDataInfo(this);
    }

    private void LoadMoreData(int pageNumber) {
        MainDataInfo_loadMore dataInfo_loadMore = new MainDataInfo_loadMore();
        // here getMainDataInfo() should return the server response
        dataInfo_loadMore.getMainDataInfo_loadMore(this, pageNumber);
    }
}
```

**Adapter codes:**

```
public class MainAdapter_loadMore extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    private List<MainDataModel> mDateSet;
    private Context mContext;

    private final int VIEW_ITEM = 1;
    private final int VIEW_PROG = 0;

    // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position
    // before loading more.
    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
    private int lastVisibleItem, totalItemCount;
    private boolean loading;
    private OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener;

    public MainAdapter_loadMore(Context context, RecyclerView recyclerView, List<MainDataModel> dataSet) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mDateSet = dataSet;

        if (recyclerView.getLayoutManager() instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {

            final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView
                    .getLayoutManager();
            recyclerView
                    .addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                               int dx, int dy) {
                            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                            totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                            lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager
                                    .findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                            if (!loading
                                    && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                                // End has been reached
                                // Do something
                                if (onLoadMoreListener != null) {
                                    onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                                }
                                loading = true;
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mDateSet.get(position) != null ? VIEW_ITEM : VIEW_PROG;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh;
        if (viewType == VIEW_ITEM) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.post_card_layout, parent, false);

            vh = new DataViewHolder(v);
        } else {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.progressbar_item, parent, false);

            vh = new ProgressViewHolder(v);
        }
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if (holder instanceof DataViewHolder) {
            ((DataViewHolder) holder).main_post_title.setText(Html.fromHtml(mDateSet.get(position).getTitle()));

            Glide.with(mContext)
                    .load(mDateSet.get(position).getThumbnail())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.post_image)
                    .crossFade()
                    .into(((DataViewHolder) holder).main_post_image);

            ((DataViewHolder) holder).main_post_content.setText(Html.fromHtml(mDateSet.get(position).getContent()));

            ((DataViewHolder) holder).main_dateTime.setText(Html.fromHtml(mDateSet.get(position).getDateTime()));

            ((DataViewHolder) holder).main_author.setText(Html.fromHtml(mDateSet.get(position).getAuthor()));

            ((DataViewHolder) holder).main_category.setText(Html.fromHtml(mDateSet.get(position).getCategory()));

            ((DataViewHolder) holder).main_post_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int pos = holder.getPosition();
                    MainDataModel model = mDateSet.get(pos);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), PostShow_page.class)
                            .putExtra("title", model.getTitle())
                            .putExtra("image", model.getThumbnail())
                            .putExtra("content", model.getContent())
                            .putExtra("dateTime", model.getDateTime())
                            .putExtra("author", model.getAuthor())
                            .putExtra("category", model.getCategory()));

                }
            });

        } else {
            ((ProgressViewHolder) holder).progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public void setLoaded() {
        loading = false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDateSet.size();
    }

    public void setOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener) {
        this.onLoadMoreListener = onLoadMoreListener;
    }

    public void remove(int position) {
        mDateSet.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    public void clear() {
        mDateSet.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public void add(List<MainDataModel> models) {
        mDateSet.addAll(models);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void update(List<MainDataModel> models) {
        mDateSet.clear();
        mDateSet.addAll(models);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class DataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView main_post_title, main_post_content, main_dateTime, main_author, main_category;
        private ImageView main_post_image;

        public DataViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            main_post_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_content_title);
            main_post_image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_picture_image);
            main_post_content = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_content_text);
            main_dateTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_date_text);
            main_author = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_name_text);
            main_category = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_category_text);
        }
    }

    public static class ProgressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public AVLoadingIndicatorView progressBar;

        public ProgressViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            progressBar = (AVLoadingIndicatorView) v.findViewById(R.id.avloadingIndicatorView);
        }
    }
}
```

I send with codes, **send datas to another activity : **

```
int pos = holder.getPosition();
                    MainDataModel model = mDateSet.get(pos);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), PostShow_page.class)
                            .putExtra("title", model.getTitle())
                            .putExtra("image", model.getThumbnail())
                            .putExtra("content", model.getContent())
                            .putExtra("dateTime", model.getDateTime())
                            .putExtra("author", model.getAuthor())
                            .putExtra("category", model.getCategory()));
```

**AsyncTask code (MainActivity) :**

```
public class MainDataInfo {
    private Context mContext;
    private String ServerAddress = ServerIP.getIP();

    public void getMainDataInfo(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        new getInfo().execute(ServerAddress + "page=1");
    }

    private class getInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        EventBus bus = EventBus.getDefault();
        private String ou_response;
        private List<MainDataModel> infoModels;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            CustomProcessDialog.createAndShow(mContext);
            infoModels = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            //String url = (String) params[0];
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(ServerAddress + "page=1")
                    .cacheControl(CacheControl.FORCE_NETWORK)
                    .build();

            Response response;
            try {
                response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                ou_response = response.body().string();
                response.body().close();
                if (ou_response != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject postObj = new JSONObject(ou_response);
                        JSONArray postsArray = postObj.optJSONArray("posts");
                        infoModels = new ArrayList<>();

                        for (int i = 0; i <= infoModels.size(); i++) {
                            JSONObject postObject = (JSONObject) postsArray.get(i);
                            // Thumbnail
                            JSONObject images = postObject.optJSONObject("thumbnail_images");
                            JSONObject imagesPair = images.optJSONObject("medium");
                            // Author
                            JSONObject Author = postObject.optJSONObject("author");
                            // Category
                            JSONArray category = postObject.getJSONArray("categories");
                            for (int j = 0; j < category.length(); j++) {
                                JSONObject categoryObject = category.getJSONObject(j);

                                int id = postObject.getInt("id");
                                String title = postObject.getString("title");
                                String content = postObject.getString("content");
                                String dateTime = postObject.getString("date");
                                String thumbnail = imagesPair.getString("url");
                                String authorShow = Author.getString("name");
                                String categoryShow = categoryObject.getString("title");

                                Log.d("Data", "Post id: " + id);
                                Log.d("Data", "Post title: " + title);
                                Log.d("Data", "Post image: " + thumbnail);
                                Log.d("Data", "Post author: " + authorShow);
                                Log.d("Data", "Post category: " + categoryShow);
                                Log.d("Data", "---------------------------------");

                                //Use the title and id as per your requirement
                                infoModels.add(new MainDataModel(id, title, content, dateTime, authorShow, categoryShow, thumbnail));
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return ou_response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            CustomProcessDialog.dissmis();
            if (result != null) {
                bus.post(infoModels);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Another Activity codes:**

```
public class PostShow_page extends AppCompatActivity implements AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener {

    private static final float PERCENTAGE_TO_SHOW_TITLE_AT_TOOLBAR = 0.9f;
    private static final float PERCENTAGE_TO_HIDE_TITLE_DETAILS = 0.3f;
    private static final int ALPHA_ANIMATIONS_DURATION = 500;

    private boolean mIsTheTitleVisible = false;
    private boolean mIsTheTitleContainerVisible = true;

    private LinearLayout mTitleContainer;
    private TextView mTitle;
    private AppBarLayout mAppBarLayout;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    private TextView postShow_title, postShow_title2, postShow_content, postShow_dateTime,
            postShow_author, postShow_category;
    private ImageView post_cover;

    private String title = "", image = "", content = "", dateTime = "", author = "", category = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.post_show_page);

        bindActivity();

        mAppBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(this);

        mToolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.post_menu);
        startAlphaAnimation(mTitle, 0, View.INVISIBLE);

        post_cover = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.postShow_cover_image);
        postShow_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.postShow_title);
        postShow_title2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.postShow_titleBig);
        postShow_content = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.postShow_content_text);
        postShow_dateTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.postShow_man_date_text);
        postShow_author = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.postShow_man_author_text);
        postShow_category = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.postShow_man_category_text);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (bundle != null) {
            title = bundle.getString("title");
            image = bundle.getString("image");
            content = bundle.getString("content");
            dateTime = bundle.getString("dateTime");
            author = bundle.getString("author");
            category = bundle.getString("category");
        }
        if (title != null) {
            postShow_title.setText(title);
            postShow_title2.setText(title);
        }
        if (image != null) {
            Glide.with(this)
                    .load(image)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.post_image)
                    .into(post_cover);
        }
        if (content != null) {
            postShow_content.setText(Html.fromHtml(content));
        }
        if (dateTime != null) {
            postShow_dateTime.setText(dateTime);
        }
        if (author != null) {
            postShow_author.setText(author);
        }
        if (category != null) {
            postShow_category.setText(category);
        }

    }
```

**How can i first downlaod image then show datas in** `PostShow_page` ?

**Attention :** Please don't give me negative points, I search in google but not find answer to my question. I am amateur and I really need you helps! thanks all <3

Comment: Why no just use any image loading library to pre-load the images?

Comment: @Ali, i use Glide for image library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using Glide to load image into imageview, you can do it in following way in order to achieve your desired functionality. Add your show data code in `onResourceReady()` method

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog= new ProgressDialog(this);
progressDialog.setMessage("Loading");
progressDialog.show();
if (image != null) { 
   Glide.with(this)
        .load(image)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.post_image)
        .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                         @Override
                         public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                             return false;
                         }

                         @Override
                         public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                             return false;
                         }
                     })
       .into(post_cover);
}
```

Comment: I use Glide library, but how can use it in `postSHow_page` , can you edit your codes with my above `postSHow_page` codes? please please, i am amateur my friend

Comment: I dont know write which code in here comment : `//Add your show data code in this method` . please help me my friend

Comment: @Palang I have modified code according to yours but it still may require few changes. Tell if you ran into any issues

Comment: Thank you man, But I mean something else is. i want show progressBar on imageview and when downloaded image show into image view and invisible progressbar

Comment: then it is more easier. I will update it again in few minutes

Comment: Thank you my dear friend, please help me i really need this, i stay here <3

Comment: instead of visible line do this progressBar.show();